# I'm not understandng why React.memo is needed on this Speaker Component to keep from extra renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got the following code (codesandbox and pasted here) that requires React.memo on the `Speaker` component.  I don't understand why it's necessary as I thought all `memo` did was to check and see if the props changed.  For the speakers that the clickCount does not change, I don't understand why memo is needed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-herschel-ptzln?file=/pages/index.js:0-1613

```
import React, { useState, memo, useCallback } from 'react';

const Speaker = memo(({ speaker, speakerClick }) => {
  console.log(speaker.id);
  return (
    <div className="speaker-col">
      <span
        onClick={() => {
          speakerClick(speaker.id);
        }}
      >
        {speaker.id} {speaker.name}
      </span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span className="fa fa-star ">&nbsp;&nbsp;{speaker.clickCount}</span>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  );
});

function SpeakerList({ speakers, setSpeakers }) {

  const speakerClick = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      // passing a callback avoid using a stale object reference
      setSpeakers((speakers) => {
        return speakers.map((speaker) => {
          return speaker.id === id
            ? { ...speaker, clickCount: speaker.clickCount + 1 }
            : speaker;
        });
      });
    },
    [setSpeakers], // you can add setSpeakers as dependency since no change
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {speakers.map((speaker) => {
        return (
          <Speaker
            speaker={speaker}
            speakerClick={speakerClick}
            key={speaker.id}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

//
const App = () => {
  const speakersArray = [
    { id: 1124, name: 'aaa', clickCount: 0 },
    { id: 1530, name: 'bbb', clickCount: 0 },
    { id: 10803, name: 'ccc', clickCount: 0 },
  ];

  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState(speakersArray);

  return (
    <div className="speakers-list">
      <h1>Speaker List</h1>
      <SpeakerList
        speakers={speakers}
        setSpeakers={setSpeakers}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memo` is a higher order `component`. If your `component renders` the same result given the same `props`, you can wrap it in a call to `React. memo` for a `performance boost` in some cases by `memoizing` the result. This means that `React` will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result. Your component will on be rendered once and wherever it's needed `React` will reuse the `previous render` which will increase it's perfomance.

In your case it seems that your `speakers` aren't changing, so the aim here was to avoid `rendering` of the `Speaker` component every time it's needed, instead it'll only be rendered once in one place and cache it and by the time it's needed in another place it won't `re-render` as `React` will use the `cached result`.

Answer (score 1):

`React.memo` is a performance optimization. As you said, it returns a memoized render result if a render with the same props is being requested.

That means that it's only relevant for components that are being rendered often with the same props, or are expensive to render (because of many or large sub components).

In this particular case, if the speakers are different, the benefits are probably minimal, unless the enclosing component gets rendered often.

Comment: I'm still not understanding why react wants to re-render that component (when not memoized)

Comment: The way react works, is that it renders the component, then compares the result to the existing component in the DOM, and if it changed, changes the DOM. It is the DOM changes that are expensive, not the render itself, mostly.